# Xamarin datepicker clear selection

Tags: c#, xamarin, datepicker, xamarin.forms

How to clear xamarin datepicker date selection from server side.
My datepicker code

```
<DatePicker x:Name="ReceiveDatePicker" TextColor="Black" IsVisible="False"></DatePicker>
```

Please suggest me the solution

Comment: What do you mean by "clear xamarin datepicker date selection from server side"?

Comment: server side????

Answer (score 2):

Theres no way to clear the selection of the Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker. Whether from "server side" or "client side", it won't work from "app-side", this I can tell.

DatePicker.Date is a DateTime property, not a Nullable DateTime.

But you can create a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) and overwrite the Control.TextView (e.g. assign string.Empty).
This does not clear the Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker.Date property though. Good Luck!